Identify year of Kona
I have a Kona Process 134 DL.  The serial number is H5AH31229 and I am trying to determine the year.  There is also a sticker EN14766.  And stamped 4, then under XL, then under T.  Can anyone help?
Thanks.


Pictures of the shifters on the Kona.


That's unfortunate I did not realize serial numbers were random. The only original components are the Rock Shox and the shifters.


Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Most manufacturers don't explain their serial numbers, but if you include some pictures of the components it might help date it.

Please review the site Tour https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour.  Also, review some other questions to see how all the "answers" you have added should be added to your original question, not placed as answers.  Bicycles SE (and all Exchange sites for that matter) are not traditional chat forums.  Thanks.

@Bob I saw you tried to edit a thanks to my answer. While I appreciate the gesture, this forum is structured such that answers only contain answers. If you want to show thanks you can upvote and accept the answer (green checkmark below votes). Glad to be of help!

Kona has an archive of their bikes available at https://archive.konaworld.com/
The archive goes back to 2016, so if your bike is older than that this method is not helpful.
Clicking through the years and searching for "134 DL" yields the following:

2021 Process 134 DL 27.5
2020 Process 134 DL 27.5
In 2019 no "DL" model of the 134 was released, only an SE version was available
In 2018 no "DL" model of the 134 was released, only an SE version was available
2017 Process 134 DL
2016 Process 134 DL

The way the rear shock connects to the frame eliminates the 2021 and 2020 models.
In your second photo it's visible that the brakes/shifters are "Shimano SLX".  Additionally, the photo also shows that the handlebar is a "Kona XC/BC".
If I look for "SLX" across the 2019-2016 models only the 2017 model mentions it on the specification. The handlebar for that model is "Kona XC/BC 35":

If this is a post-2015 bike, it's likely the 2017 model based on the components.
However, the stickering does differ strongly between your bike and the  archive photos of the 2017 model (e.g. the logo on the headtube). I'm not an expert, so I don't know if such a difference is common, or if this is in an indicator that it's actually a different model.
